# What is the kill score of all dragons and dragon-riders during the Dance of the Dragons?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, dragons, kill-count

The [**Dance of the Dragons**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dance_of_the_Dragons) was a wide-scale civil war between two factions of House Targaryen headed by Princess [Rhaenyra Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenyra_Targaryen) and Prince [Aegon II Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_II_Targaryen) who were both vying for the throne of their [father](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Viserys_I_Targaryen).

Dragons fought against other dragons and most of them died as a result.

What is the kill score of each dragon and its rider involved in the Dance? Which Dragon and Dragonrider scored the most kills in the war?

Comment: “Which Dragon and Dragonrider scored the most kills in the war?” It’s not a competition!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Apologies, of course [Aerial warfare is serious business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_War_II_flying_aces) ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Top Aces of Dance of the Dragons

In Dragons, Vhagar and Sunfyre were most successful with 3 kills each.

In Dragonriders, Prince Aemond and King Aegon II were most successful with 3 kills each.

---

### Score List of Dragons

Following is a completed compilation of the Ace dragons involved and their respective kills during the conflict:

1. [**Vhagar**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Vhagar): Vhagar killed 2 dragons ([Arrax](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dance_of_the_Dragons#The_Dance_over_Shipbreaker_Bay) and [Caraxes](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_Above_the_Gods_Eye)) and comes out as the ace of the war. Further more Vhagar shares credit for killing [Meleys the Red Queen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_at_Rook%27s_Rest) with Sunfyre the Golden. That makes the total tally for Vhagar **3**.
2. [**Sunfyre**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sunfyre): Sunfyre ties with Vhagar for the top place. Sunfyre killed 2 dragons ([Moon Dancer](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fall_of_Dragonstone) and [Grey Ghost](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Grey_Ghost#History)). Sunfyre shares credit with Vhagar for killing [Meleys the Red Queen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_at_Rook%27s_Rest). That makes total tally for Sunfyre **3**. If we discount Grey Ghost based on the reason that it was not aligned with the warring parties, Sunfyre's score becomes 2.
3. [**Tessarion**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tessarion): Tessarion shares credit for killing [Vermithor](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Second_Battle_of_Tumbleton) with Seasmoke. Tessarion also shares credit for killing [Seasmoke](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Second_Battle_of_Tumbleton) with Vermithor even though it was Vermithor who dealt the killing blow. That makes score of Tessarion **2**.
4. [**Vermithor**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Vermithor): Vermithor killed [Seasmoke](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Second_Battle_of_Tumbleton). That makes score for Vermithor **1**.
5. [**Seasmoke**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Seasmoke): Sea Smoke shares credit for [victory against Vermithor](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Second_Battle_of_Tumbleton) with Tessarion. It makes Sea Smoke's score **1**.
6. [**Caraxes**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Caraxes): Caraxes killed [Vhagar](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_Above_the_Gods_Eye). That makes Caraxes' score **1**. This kill is most impressive because Vhagar was the largest dragon in the World at that time. The battle ended with both Dragons killed even though Caraxes died after Vhagar.

Other dragons failed to register any kills during the conflict. So to sum it all up, following table contains entries for all the dragons which were present at the time of the conflict:

| Dragon | Independent Kills | Shared Kills | Total Kills | Survived the War |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vhagar | 2 | 1 | 3 | No |
| Sunfyre | 2 | 1 | 3 | No |
| Tessarion | 0 | 2 | 2 | No |
| Vermithor | 1 | 0 | 1 | No |
| Sea Smoke | 0 | 1 | 1 | No |
| Caraxes | 1 | 0 | 1 | No |
| Silverwing | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| Dreamfyre | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Meleys | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Syrax | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Vermax | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Arrax | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Tyraxes | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Moon Dancer | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Stormcloud | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Morghul | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Shrykos | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Sheep Stealer | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| Grey Ghost | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Cannibal | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| Morning | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |

---

### Score List of Dragonriders

The Dragonriders who managed to score a kill or more during the war were:

1. Prince [**Aemond Targaryen**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aemond_Targaryen): Prince Aemond killed his nephew Prince [Lucerys Velaryon](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lucerys_Velaryon) and Lucerys' dragon in battle above Storm's End, winning the first aerial victory of the war and second ever in Westerosi history. Later he joined forces with his brother King [Aegon II](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_II_Targaryen) to kill their cousin Princess [Rhaenys Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenys_Targaryen_(daughter_of_Aemon)) and her dragon. In his final battle, the Prince faced his uncle Prince [Daemon Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_Targaryen). Aemond and Daemon both died in the battle that ensured above God's Eye. That makes his total tally **3**.
2. King [**Aegon II Targaryen**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_II_Targaryen): Aegon II was the leader of Green Faction of House Targaryen and eldest living son of King [Viserys I](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Viserys_I_Targaryen) when his father died. His first kill came from his battle against Princess [Rhaenys Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenys_Targaryen_(daughter_of_Aemon)) which he shared with his brother Aemond. Later the King and his dragon killed a wild dragon named Grey Ghost on Dragonstone. During his conquest of Dragonstone, Aegon faced his cousin [Baela Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Baela_Targaryen). He successfully killed Baela's dragon and took her captive. His own legs however shattered in the fight and his dragon succumbed to his wounds a few weeks later. That makes his total score **3**, putting him in a tie with his brother Aemond for the top position.
3. Ser [**Addam Velaryon**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Addam_Velaryon): The loyal servant of Queen Rhaenyra Targaryen and heir to Lord Corlys Velaryon, Ser Addam and his dragon killed Vermithor in Tumbleton with help of Tessarion. Ser Addam however did not survive the battle and died as well. His score remains **1** for shared (posthumous) victory against Vermithor.
4. Prince [**Daemon Targaryen**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_Targaryen): The man known as the rogue Prince made his sole kill in battle against his nephew Aemond. He launched a suicide attack when faced with desperate odds against World's largest Dragon Vhagar. He managed to kill his nephew and Vhagar but he died as well due to the fall. His corpse was never found in the lake of God's Eye. His score is **1** but his 1 kill is Vhagar so he virtually wins.

So if we were to draw a table for kills of respective Dragonriders, we would get the following result:

| Dragonrider | Independent Kills | Shared Kills | Total Kills | Survived the War |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prince Aemond Targaryen | 2 | 1 | 3 | No |
| King Aegon II Targaryen | 2 | 1 | 3 | No |
| Ser Addam Velaryon | 0 | 1 | 1 | No |
| Prince Daemon Targaryen | 1 | 0 | 1 | No |
| Ulf the White | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Queen Helaena Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Princess Rhaenys Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Queen Rhaenyra Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Prince Jacaerys Velaryon | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Prince Lucerys Velaryon | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Prince Joffrey Velaryon | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Lady Baela Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| King Aegon III Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| Prince Jaehaerys Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Queen Jaehaera Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| Nettles | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| Prince Daeron Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Hard Hugh Hammer | 0 | 0 | 0 | No |
| Lady Rhaena Targaryen | 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |

---

**NOTE:** Prince Daeron and Hard Hugh Hammer don't have any kills to their names because their dragons won their kill points while being riderless. Also it must be noted that Queen Jaehaera Targaryen and her brother Jaehaerys were not technically dragon riders. They were bonded to the dragons but they never actually rode them. They are in the list just for the sake of completion.

Comment: Which book is it described in this detail? And a small question: What is the lifespan of a dragon assuming no maesters try to kill it and there is no war?

Comment: @C.Koca The Dance of the dragons is covered in The Princess and the Queen. It was published in Dangerous Women anthology. You can also read the Rogue Prince in this regard.

Comment: As for your second question, I don't believe we know anything except that a Dragon never stops growing. Lifespan of Balerion the Blackdread would be helpful. Balerion came from Valyria with Aenar Targaryen to dragonstone. It died in reign of King Jaehaerys I.

Comment: Dragons are like turtles; giant, flying, fire-breathing turtles!

Comment: didn't the cannibal kill and eat one of the bigger dragons?

Comment: @Termatinator Cannibal was fond of eating dragon babies. The Dragon that was mistook for Cannibal was actually Sunfyre the Golden, who'd killed Greyghost and eaten its corpse.

Comment: @Aegon maybe still include that bit of the cannibal as some trivia? (s)he did probably kill lots of dragons, even though they were babies

Comment: @Termatinator that is correct but the question is focused on Kills during the Dance, and all of cannibal's trips to the hatcheries that we know of are before the dance, not during it. For all we know, there might not have been any hatchlings during that period since Prince Viserys and Princess Rhaena were given eggs, not hatchlings.