# Was the birth of Daenerys' dragons due to these previous events or are they unrelated?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Game of Thrones*

> Daenerys' son Rhaego was stillborn due to a blood magic ritual performed by Mirri Maz Duur.

Later

> her dragons are born

Was this some kind of "exchange"?

Comment: [Related essay](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/159029/68872) from Aegon

Comment: The subsection titled "How did Daenerys do it" in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/159022/68872) seems to cover this question _extensively_. This is however still a great question to ask!

Comment: @Edlothiad I agree that it is answered, however I would like to say that it wasn't asked (properly).

Comment: No it wasn't, and that's why I gave you a nice big fat upvote, called it a great question and even suggested upvotes in our aSoIaF chatroom! It's a good question and worthy of rep, but simply copying and pasting content isn't the best way to manage the site :)